# ''The following updates have been kept back'' & ''19 were not upgraded''

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, 22.04

I'm creating this thread because I've just installed Ubuntu **22.04 LTS** on my laptop. Everything went according to plan except for one thing.

When I wanted to perform an update and upgrade in my terminal I noticed this was being displayed.

The following packages have been held back:

```
gnome-remote-desktop gstreamer1.0-pipewire libegl-mesa0 libgbm1
  libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libpipewire-0.3-0
  libpipewire-0.3-common libpipewire-0.3-modules libspa-0.2-modules
  libxatracker2 mesa-vulkan-drivers openssh-client pipewire pipewire-bin
  python3-software-properties software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk
```

What I have also noticed is that 19 packages were not upgraded I've tried to force upgrade it by running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but had no luck whatsoever I've tried using Google and stumbled across a few threads where they told the user to update the individual package by running `sudo apt upgrade <package name>` but in my case it brought me in a whole loop hole of errors and such.

So I had a bunch of questions regarding this:

- Is this a necessary upgrade I should be worried about (if yes how do you solve this)?
- And last but not least what effect will this have if I decide not to upgrade these packages?

I'm looking very forward to you guys your answers and hope to solve the issue and learn something new out of this thread!

Thanks folks.